# How to delete the current row in pandas dataframe during df.iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to delete the current row during iteration - `using df.iterrows()`, if it its certain column fails on my `if` condition.

ex.

```
for index, row in df:
     if row['A'] == 0:
          #remove/drop this row from the df
          del df[index] #I tried this but it gives me an error
```

This might be a very easy one, but i still can't figure out how to do it.
Your help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I don't know if this is pseudo code or not but you can't delete a row like this, you can `drop` it:

```
In [425]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[425]:
          a         b
0 -1.348112  0.583603
1  0.174836  1.211774
2 -2.054173  0.148201
3 -0.589193 -0.369813
4 -1.156423 -0.967516
In [426]:

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['a'] > 0:
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)
In [427]:

df
Out[427]:
          a         b
0 -1.348112  0.583603
2 -2.054173  0.148201
3 -0.589193 -0.369813
4 -1.156423 -0.967516
```

if you just want to filter those rows out you can perform boolean indexing:

```
df[df['a'] <=0]
```

would achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I tried [@EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) solution with a custom `pandas.DataFrame`, but I did not get it working as an error was raising: `KeyError: '[78] not found in axis'`. So on, if you got the same error, it can be fixed dropping the index of the dataframe on the specified index on each **.iterrows()** iteration.

The dataframe used was retrieved from [investpy](https://github.com/alvarob96/investpy) which contains all the equities/stock data indexed in [Investing.com](https://www.investing.com/), and the print function is the one implemented in [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html). Anyways, this is the piece of code to get it working:

```
In [1]:

import investpy
from pprint import pprint

In [2]:

df = investpy.get_equities()

pprint(df.head())

Out [2]:

     country               name                           full_name  \
0  argentina            Tenaris                             Tenaris   
1  argentina       PETROBRAS ON     Petroleo Brasileiro - Petrobras   
2  argentina     GP Fin Galicia          Grupo Financiero Galicia B   
3  argentina  Ternium Argentina  Ternium Argentina Sociedad Anónima   
4  argentina      Pampa Energía                  Pampa Energía S.A.   

                      tag          isin     id currency  
0       tenaris?cid=13302  LU0156801721  13302      ARS  
1  petrobras-on?cid=13303  BRPETRACNOR9  13303      ARS  
2          gp-fin-galicia  ARP495251018  13304      ARS  
3                 siderar  ARSIDE010029  13305      ARS  
4           pampa-energia  ARP432631215  13306      ARS  

In [3]:

pprint(df[df['tag'] == 'koninklijke-philips-electronics'])

Out [3]:

      country                     name                   full_name  \
78  argentina  Koninklijke Philips DRC  Koninklijke Philips NV DRC   

                                tag          isin     id currency  
78  koninklijke-philips-electronics  ARDEUT110558  30044      ARS  

In [4]:

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['tag'] == 'koninklijke-philips-electronics':
        df.drop(df.index[index], inplace=True)

In [5]:

pprint(df[df['tag'] == 'koninklijke-philips-electronics'])

Out [5]:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [country, name, full_name, tag, isin, id, currency]
Index: []
```

Hope this helped someone! Also thank you anyways for the original answer [@EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum)!